# AWS Changing default region when deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

i would like to know if there is a way to set default region in AWS. In my specific case if i deploy a next.js app on Amplify on server eu-central, the S3 Bucket and Lambda functions are stored in us-south by default. Is there a way to change this behavior? I deploy by linking a GitHub repository and then choice the role. So the problem is that Amplify hosts the site in Europe while S3 and Lambda store data in USA.

Comment: All AWS deployment tooling supports the selection of region, whether implicit (as in the AWS console) or explicit (as with a --region xyz command line parameter or equivalent). Also, not sure what you mean by us-south.